# Submit iPhone app for iPhone 5 and up only, no iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to release my first iPhone app. When I started this project about 2 years ago, I designed and developed the views on my iPhone5 and tested them all on the iPhone5s and beyond simulators. Didn't think I needed to developed for anything below the iPhone5. It will also take a huge effort to developed below the iPhone 5 and with not much benefit.

My app got rejected because it is not usable on the iPhone3Gs and iPad which are lower resolutions. My app works perfectly on iPhone5 and above.

In xCode, Devices is set to iPhone (not iPad or Universal). Think it is very misleading since Apple will reject if your app doesn't work on an iPad.

Is there any way around this?

I heard you can constrain your app to be 64-bit only which will make it only work with iPhone5 and above (anyone know how to do this), however there is still a constraint with the iPad Air which is 64-bit and the lower resolution.

If this is not possible, what is the easiest way to developed views for the iPhone3gs separately. I don't want to touch the current ones (iPhone 5 and above) because they work and look great.

Thanks :(

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing the 1x images resolution.

For each image you use in you app your need now 3 resolutions 1x, 2x and 3x.

for example:

```
image.png 40x40
image@2x.png 80x80
image@3x.png 120x120
```

1x is for 3gs, ipad 2 and ipad mini 1.
3x is for iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone 6s Plus.
2x is for all the others devices.

Comment: What about all my labels, textfields, etc that are all placed in specific locations, using the whole screen for the iPhone5. Specifially when currently viewed on a iPhone3gs, buttons don't show up because they are too far down for the iPhone3gs screen but show up on the iPhone5

Comment: Then you should use autolayout. Take a look on this tutorial [Autolayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)